# Double tap zoom on image

Tags: android

Hi I'm working in double tap zoom effect on image.whenever I double click the image its getting zoomin and zoom out(function is working correctly).But during zoom in and zoom out image is shaking .it's not getting smooth zoom effect.

i got the code from this link

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

please share your ideas for smooth touble tap zooming effect.

thanks in advance

Comment: try this library https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: while importing its showing error